# localhost web server on win10 with no admin

Tags: windows, windows-10

so, I want to create a web server and store it into my computer (it's a win10 btw) and i am not the admin.
and when I search localhost it shows an image that if I click it will send me to the IIS site.
pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

Disable it IIS :)
there is no reason to install it or have it installed if you dont use it

Hit the Windows-key type: "Add or Remove Programs". If you get the new Settings app of win10
You have look to right top corner
from there click Add/Remove Windows Components.
Select the Internet Information Services (IIS) uncheck box, click Next, then click Finish.

than try to host your server again

Comment: i dont have it installed

Comment: it gives me this: [link](https://gyazo.com/179c8025242c841a01ee7671a0a251c2)

Comment: and what i want is to host it into my computer